# Preventing duplicate entries in Multi Instance Application Environment

Tags: multithreading, facebook, jdbc, concurrency, server-side

I am writing an application to serve facebook APIs; share, like etc.. I am keeping all those shared objects from my appliction in a database and I do not want to share the same object if it already been shared.

Considering I will deploy application on different servers there could be a case where both instance tries to insert the same object to table.

How can I manage this concurrency problem with blocking the applications fully ? I mean two threads will try to insert same object and they must sync but they should not block a 3rd thread where it is inserting totally different object.

Comment: If there's a way to derive primary key of data entry from data itself, database will resolve such concurrency issue by itself -- 2nd insert will fail with 'Primary Key constraint violation'. Perhaps, data supplied by Facebook API already have some unique ID?

Comment: exactly it is. I was thinking some other magical things but seems this gonna be the only way. I can set as answer If you wrote this as an answer but not comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there's a way to derive primary key of data entry from data itself, database will resolve such concurrency issue by itself -- 2nd insert will fail with 'Primary Key constraint violation'. Perhaps, data supplied by Facebook API already have some unique ID?

Or, you can consider some distributed lock solution, for example, based on Hazelcast or on similar data grid. This would allow to have record state shared by different JVMs, so it will be possible to avoid unneeded `INSERTS`.